# SQLCMD LIKE query returns more records than expected

Tags: sqlcmd

I have a sqlcmd utility file that is returning far more records than expected.  Here is the essential structure of the file:

```
sqlcmd -S %1 -d %2
"Set NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT
col1,
col2,
col3
FROM some_table
WHERE
(
col1 LIKE '%text1%' OR col1 LIKE '%text2%'
OR
col2 LIKE '%text1%' OR col2 LIKE '%text2%'
OR
col3 LIKE '%text1%' OR col3 LIKE '%text2%'
)"
-s "      "
-o some_output_file.txt
```

The stuff in the -s line is actually a tab character to make the output file be tab-delimited.  I'm getting my entire some_table returning in this query.  It should only return just a few records out of it.  I have tested the SQL in SQL Server, and it works fine.  However, when I run this with sqlcmd (via Command line), it returns the entire some_table.  I don't know why.  I think it may have something to do with wildcard characters in sqlcmd, but I haven't been able to find any documentation.

Comment: For such long query it's better to use -i option and put a query into separate file.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what my error was.  Since I am doing this via a Command prompt (i.e., a batch file), I need to escape the percent signs, as they are interpreted as by Windows.  So, for the LIKEs, I need to escape them by using %% instead of just %.